# How to turn my legend horizontal as opposed to vertical with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, phyloseq

I am struggling to understand why `legend.horizontal` is not rotating my legend axis so it isn't displaying vertically? Any help would be massively appreciated.

```r
library(phyloseq)
library(ggplot2)

##phylum level 
ps_tmp <- get_top_taxa(physeq_obj = ps.phyl, n = 10, relative = TRUE, discard_other = FALSE, other_label = "Other") 
ps_tmp <- name_taxa(ps_tmp, label = "Unkown", species = T, other_label = "Other")
phyl <- fantaxtic_bar(ps_tmp, color_by = "phylum", label_by = "phylum",facet_by = "TREATMENT", other_label = "Other", order_alg = "as.is")
phyl + theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom", )
```

[image: Example of plot + legend displayed vertically]

Comment: I don't know the package you're using, so can't test, but instead of `legend.direction()` something like '+ guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE)) +' might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legends for discrete values don't have a formal direction per se and are positioned however `ggplot2` decides it can best fit with your data.  This is why things like `legend.direction` won't work here.  I don't have the `phyloseq` package or access to your particular data, so I'll show you how this works and how you can mess with the legend using a reproducible example dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:8], y=sample(1:100, 8))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=x)) + geom_col()
p
```

[image]

By default, ggplot is putting our legend to the right and organizes it vertically as one column.  Here's what happens when we move the legend to the bottom:

```
p + theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Now ggplot thinks it's best to put that legend into 4 columns, 2 rows each.  As u/Tech Commodities mentioned, you can use the `guides()` functions to specify how the legend looks.  In this case, we will specify to have 2 columns instead of 4.  We only need to supply the number of columns (or rows), and ggplot figures out the rest.

```
p + theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

[image]

So, to get a "horizontally-arranged" legend, you just need to specify that there should be only one row:

```
p + theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=1))
```

[image]